# Running java -cp command for a maven project in intellij IDE

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project in intellij on windows.

Inside, I have a package with a file inside it:

[image]

build generates a jar named as 'outputjar':

[image]

I want to run  java -cp command for the class, and tried various ways:

```
java -cp \target\outputjar\java\main\ jvm.LongRunningAlloc &
java -cp \target\outputjar jvm.LongRunningAlloc &
java -cp absolute-path-to-jar jvm.LongRunningAlloc &
```

But none works.

I always get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class jvm.LongRunningAlloc
```

What is correct way of doing it?

Comment: What is the package name for the `LongRunningAlloc` class?  What does it say in the source code?

Comment: It is: package jvm;

Comment: Since you’re using an ide, then why not take advantage of that and just create a run/debug config and run from the class instead of first creating the jar and running from there?

Comment: And within the JAR file, what is the full name of the entry for the `LongRunningAlloc` class?  (Use `jar -tvf absolute-path-to-jar` to find out.)

Comment: You should generally be building an executable jar so only `java -jar outputjar.jar` should be necessary